# Powder 3D Printer

Tags: diy-3d-printer

I purchased a Z Corp Printer more than 10 years ago and wonder what I can do with it now.  Everything has gone to the Extrude method rather than the additive method.  Am I the proud owner of a fancy boat anchor.
[image]

Comment: `Everything has gone to the Extrude method rather than the additive method`; no, only the *hobbyist* 3D printing scene has gone to the extrude method (FDM). In professional contexts, other methods of 3D printing (including your Z-Corp machine) are as popular as ever.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search of the interweb shows that 3D Systems purchased ZCorp many years ago. A short review of the printer prior to the purchase also shows that the printer had, as one of the many negative points, a problem with sourcing printing supplies, as it is considered proprietary.

Additional searching brought up articles suggesting that one could create the media using common materials or by mixing other common materials, but the article I found did not expound beyond referencing gypsum powder and a couple other "normal" items.

If you have working software and perform a search for the specific model number combined with the words "printing supplies," you may find additional insight into creating your own media. One article suggested that you could print with sugar, a rather novel concept.

The killer with devices of this type is the proprietary handle.

This appears to be the sort of device that appears on Craigslist or abandoned in an estate sale. If you were local to me, I'd make an offer for the value of the internal components, although I'd also take a shot at printing with sugar or similar granular material. The idea of a laundry detergent Benchy comes to mind.

Comment: Come to think of it.  I heard at some time that it could use Alcohol of some sort.  Might have been Vodka but I don't know what the medium would be.